# Call the StaticLayout getHeight. it return Wrong height. not equal with the view truly height

Tags: android

```
 animView.post(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
           new StaticLayout(
                animView.getText(),
                animView.getPaint(),
                animView.getMeasuredWidth(),
                Layout.Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL,
                animView.getLineSpacingMultiplier()
                ,animView.getLineSpacingExtra(),
                true);
}
```

then I call the getHeight() of this StaticLayout.but it result is not equal with animView.getHeight().
I don't know why?

Answer (score 0):

use TextView inner staticLayout call params to use StaticLayout can get right height and width.

```
StaticLayout.Builder builder = StaticLayout.Builder.obtain(mTransformed,
                0, mTransformed.length(), mTextPaint, wantWidth)
                .setAlignment(alignment)
                .setTextDirection(mTextDir)
                .setLineSpacing(mSpacingAdd, mSpacingMult)
                .setIncludePad(mIncludePad)
                .setUseLineSpacingFromFallbacks(mUseFallbackLineSpacing)
                .setBreakStrategy(mBreakStrategy)
                .setHyphenationFrequency(mHyphenationFrequency)
                .setJustificationMode(mJustificationMode)
                .setMaxLines(mMaxMode == LINES ? mMaximum : Integer.MAX_VALUE);
```

The all params can get from you own TextView.